# Difficulty understanding second parameter of inet_ntop() in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a basic webserver in C++ based on a tutorial given here:

https://vichargrave.github.io/articles/2013-02/tcp-ip-network-programming-design-patterns-in-cpp

and am having trouble understanding the following line:

```
inet_ntop(PF_INET, (struct in_addr*)&(address->sin_addr.s_addr), ip, sizeof(ip)-1);
```

Specifically I am having trouble understanding what the second parameter:

```
(struct in_addr*)&(address->sin_addr.s_addr)
```

is doing. This parameter is in a syntax I haven't seen before and based on what I know it is doing one of two things:

it is ANDing a struct `in_addr` pointer with the given field in address or

it is casting the address of `address->sin_addr.s_addr` to a pointer of `struct in_addr*`

Which one is it?

Edit:
So it seems that it is a cast. Which leads me to another question. That parameter seems to be casting a variable of type `in_addr_t` to a struct which doesn't make sense. Is this the correct view of it or is it doing something else?

Also, I am referencing the following page for documentation on this function:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/netinetin.h.html
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_ntop.html

Comment: `struct in_addr*` is a type, not an object, how can you AND it with anything?

Comment: So its casting it then. Like I said I wasn't sure. I'm still new to C++ so I didn't want to continue on my project with an assumption that could have been wrong.

Comment: @AbdusSalamKhazi: on many systems, the `AF_... ` and `PF_... ` defines are the same value. But you are right, the `AF_... ` defines are more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better understanding read it from right to left.

```
(struct in_addr*)&(address->sin_addr.s_addr)
```

So,

```
address->sin_addr.s_addr --> uses the "address" ptr to access sin_addr.s_addr
```

then

```
&(address->sin_addr.s_addr) takes the address of s_addr.
```

then

```
(struct in_addr*) casts the address taken by & to in_addr.
```

The above makes sense because the following 2 are equivalent in this case

```
(struct in_addr*)&(address->sin_addr.s_addr) 
(struct in_addr*)&(address->sin_addr)
```

The address of the struct is the same as the address of its first member in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks! This helps answer my first question. This leads me to another question which I posted in an edit above. How can you cast a variable to a struct? My understanding is that this is a basic datatype like int or uint8_t.

Comment: How can you cast a variable to a struct? --> Here we are not casting the variable per say, we are casting a pointer to a variable to a pointer to a struct. The compiler will not complain about pointer casts since it assumes that you know what you are doing (as you have done it explicitly).

Comment: I understand that they are pointers casts and not direct variable casts but I thought pointers of one type cannot point to another type? So how can a pointer of type `struct in_addr` point to s_addr which is a variable of type `in_addr_t`?

Comment: @aprdrivesmecrazy, The above makes sense because the following 2 are equivalent in this case

    (struct in_addr*)&(address->sin_addr.s_addr) 
    (struct in_addr*)&(address->sin_addr)

The address of the struct is the same as the address of its first member in C/C++. (Check my edited answer)

Comment: @AbdusSalamKhazi: C++ compilers don't complain about C style casts, because they can't validate them. You should favor C++ style casts instead, which allows the compiler to validate casts.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, it is indeed casting the *address* of the `address->sin_addr.s_addr` field to a `struct in_addr*` pointer. Since the question is tagged `c++`, a C++ style cast would make this clearer:

```
inet_ntop(PF_INET, reinterpret_cast<struct in_addr*>(&(address->sin_addr.s_addr)), ip, sizeof(ip)-1);
```

To answer your second question, it is not casting a variable itself to a pointer. It is casting the *address* of the variable to a different pointer type. In this case, the *address* of the `s_addr` field is casted to a `struct in_addr*` pointer. The address of the first field of a type is the same as the address of the type itself. So it is technically safe to cast the *address* of `s_addr` to `struct in_addr*`.

However, that being said, the cast is *redundant* and should be removed. The second parameter of `inet_ntop()` is a `const void*`, and any pointer can be assigned as_is to a `void*`.  When the first parameter is `(AF|PF)_INET`, the second parameter must be a pointer to a `struct in_addr`, so you should use the address of the `sin_addr` field itself (which is an actual `in_addr`), not its `s_addr` field (which is a field inside of the `in_addr`):

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(address->sin_addr), ip, sizeof(ip)-1);
```

If you have an IPv6 address (the first parameter is `(AF|PF)_INET6`), the second parameter must be a pointer to a `struct in6_addr`, which would be the `sin6_addr` field of a `sockaddr_in6`:

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(address->sin6_addr), ip, sizeof(ip)-1);
```

In order to support both families (the primary reason  for using `inet_ntop()` in the first place), `address` should be a pointer to a `struct sockaddr_storage` (which is large enough to hold any `struct sockaddr_...` type, but in this case IPv4 and IPv6 addresses), and `ip` needs to be at least 46 chars (best to use the `INET6_ADDRSTRLEN` define for that). Then you can do the following:

```
switch (address->ss_family) 
{
    case AF_INET:
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(address)->sin_addr), ip, sizeof(ip)-1);
        break;
    case AF_INET6:
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in6*>(address)->sin6_addr), ip, sizeof(ip)-1);
        break;
}
```